# Deselect a collectionview cell when another cell is selected

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have cells with images on a `viewController`, I like to give the users an option to select one of the `image` for their `title label`. How do I make them select only one `image`, that is if they select another `image` I want to deselect the previous `image` they selected.

This is what I did:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
            cell?.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
            cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        }
```

but it is allowing me to select all cells not just one cell which I like.

Comment: You should set `collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false` in `viewDidLoad` and not every time something is selected.

Comment: I did but it still allows me to select multiple cells

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, move  `collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false` to `viewDidLoad`

Secondly, I don't think you really have a problem with multiple selection. Rather that you don't clear the effects you put on the cell when selecting it. What you can do is to clear that i `didDeselect`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        cell?.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
        cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        cell?.layer.borderWidth = 0
        cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

    }
```

Comment: Not working for me. DeselectedItem will never called.

Comment: This only works when all the cells are in view, if you select a cell and scroll out of screen and select something else, now you have two things that appear to be selected.

Comment: @NSCoder hey having same issue

Comment: Solved it after some trial and error. thanks

Comment: for those who are facing a crash once selecting after scrolling while selecting a cell, you have to do as he mentioned in he's comment :
set collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false in viewDidLoad